# Phaser scrolling background

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

My goal is to make a sprite bigger than the screen and have the user scroll to see the different parts of it, so I wanted to ask if Phaser had any sprite `eventListener`-functions such as:

```
    var canvas = window.document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0],
        prevX = 0, prevY = 0, mouseDown = false;
```

where canvas can be used as

```
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e){
    });

   canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did it.

In your update function:

```js
if (this.game.input.activePointer.isDown) { 
  if (this.game.origDragPoint) {    
    // move the camera by the amount the mouse has moved since last update
    this.game.camera.x += this.game.origDragPoint.x - this.game.input.activePointer.position.x;
    this.game.camera.y += this.game.origDragPoint.y - this.game.input.activePointer.position.y;
  }
  // set new drag origin to current position
  this.game.origDragPoint = this.game.input.activePointer.position.clone();
}
else {
  this.game.origDragPoint = null;
}
```

Comment: this works well, only problem is that on week mobile devices there is noticeable performance issue.. at this point could not find a better way

Answer (score 0):

If using the camera is OK for you, you can try this Phaser 2 plugin: https://jdnichollsc.github.io/Phaser-Kinetic-Scrolling-Plugin/

With this plugin you can enable vertical and horizontal scroll to simulate scrolling into the canvas element used by Phaser, also you can customize the movement before to initialize the plugin, example:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(400, 400, Phaser.AUTO, '', {
  init: function () {

    //Load the plugin
    this.game.kineticScrolling = this.game.plugins.add(Phaser.Plugin.KineticScrolling);
  },
  create: function () {

    //Configure the plugin
    this.game.kineticScrolling.configure({
      kineticMovement: true,
      timeConstantScroll: 325, //really mimic iOS
      horizontalScroll: true,
      verticalScroll: false,
      horizontalWheel: true,
      verticalWheel: false,
      deltaWheel: 40
    });

    //Starts the plugin
    this.game.kineticScrolling.start();

    //Changing the world size
    this.game.world.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 800);
  },
  stopScrolling: function () {
    //Stop the plugin
    this.game.kineticScrolling.stop();
  }
});
```

Also there's a fork for Phaser 3, check the repo from GitHub.

Regards, Nicholls